# Package EXT does not exist

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am currently working through the Land of Lisp examples and have run into a compile exception: package EXT does not exist
from this line I suspect:
`(ext:shell  (concatenate 'string "dot -Tpng -O" fname))`

I am running my repl inside emacs with slime and am unsure as to how to remedy this after some googling of the error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your platform? Where did you get CLISP? How are you invoking it? Please see [how to report bugs](http://clisp.org/impnotes/clisp.html#bugs)

Comment: I run arch Linux and have been using yaourt/ pac-man for all my packages. I believe that I also have sbcl installed and am unsure if emacs and the swank framework is using clisp or sbcl. I'm going to do a little more investigation into it, was just a little frustrated. Is the ext package a default library for clisp?

Comment: Yes, CLISP comes with EXT by default. You cannot build CLISP without it. See also http://clisp.org/impnotes/imppack.html

Comment: I just ran CLISP from my shell and loaded my file in and all works correct. I suspect that emacs and the swank framework is to blame, either in it doesn't use CLISP or some other unseen error(the investigation continues). Thanks for your time.

Comment: Btw.: SBCL has similar ways to call an external program. See: http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Running-external-programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was in fact that SBCL was set as the default lisp program in emacs.

By replacing:

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/bin/sbcl")
```

To:

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/bin/clisp")
```

in my emacs configuration file fixed the issue. (On a Unix system at least)